# Ubuntu boot stuck at "btrfs loaded crc32c=crc32c-intel zoned=yes fsverity=yes"

Tags: boot, 22.04, raid, btrfs

I've been stuck on this for 5 days now, so any help would be appreciated>
This is a bare metal server on OVH running Ubuntu 22.04. The OS was installed on a RAID1 array using both "system disks" (these are regular SSDs).
The issue appears when creating a RAID10 array of the 6 "data disks" we have (these are nvme disks). Upon creating the partition on the array (ext4), mounting it and amending fstab and mdadm.conf, the OS will not boot.
Here's the `lsblk` printout:

```
loop0         7:0    0  63.9M  1 loop   /snap/core20/2105
loop1         7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop   /snap/lxd/24322
loop2         7:2    0  40.9M  1 loop   /snap/snapd/20290
loop3         7:3    0  40.4M  1 loop   /snap/snapd/20671
sda           8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   511M  0 part
├─sda2        8:2    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0  1022M  0 raid1  /boot
├─sda3        8:3    0 445.1G  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0   445G  0 raid1  /
├─sda4        8:4    0   512M  0 part   [SWAP]
└─sda5        8:5    0     2M  0 part
sdb           8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:17   0   511M  0 part   /boot/efi
├─sdb2        8:18   0     1G  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0  1022M  0 raid1  /boot
├─sdb3        8:19   0 445.1G  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0   445G  0 raid1  /
└─sdb4        8:20   0   512M  0 part   [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0   3.5T  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:6    0   3.5T  0 part
  └─md127     9:127  0  10.5T  0 raid10 /db
nvme1n1     259:1    0   3.5T  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1 259:8    0   3.5T  0 part
  └─md127     9:127  0  10.5T  0 raid10 /db
nvme2n1     259:2    0   3.5T  0 disk
└─nvme2n1p1 259:9    0   3.5T  0 part
  └─md127     9:127  0  10.5T  0 raid10 /db
nvme3n1     259:3    0   3.5T  0 disk
└─nvme3n1p1 259:10   0   3.5T  0 part
  └─md127     9:127  0  10.5T  0 raid10 /db
nvme4n1     259:4    0   3.5T  0 disk
└─nvme4n1p1 259:11   0   3.5T  0 part
  └─md127     9:127  0  10.5T  0 raid10 /db
nvme5n1     259:5    0   3.5T  0 disk
└─nvme5n1p1 259:12   0   3.5T  0 part
  └─md127     9:127  0  10.5T  0 raid10 /db
```

**fstab**:

```
UUID=9079d740-3f55-4f57-880b-56f6a628494f       /       ext4    defaults        0       1
UUID=e780ca2c-b474-4ae9-9c1d-6224a23fca6b       /boot   ext4    defaults        0       0
LABEL=EFI_SYSPART       /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
UUID=d3ebca74-ffff-4b55-a9e4-70c002e3edf5       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
UUID=b8298672-7b7c-48bf-9022-9d9408adafeb       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
UUID=257b2715-613a-44c7-8744-7c159764c09a       /db     ext4    defaults        0       0
```

**mdadm.conf:**

definitions of existing MD arrays

```
ARRAY /dev/md/md2  metadata=1.2 UUID=109fefd8:aa46fdd6:bddb613e:892bce00 name=md2
ARRAY /dev/md/md3  metadata=1.2 UUID=950bfa3c:f52d5cfd:9f9c1435:0d85a63f name=md3
```

This configuration was auto-generated on Sun, 14 Jan 2024 18:51:06 +0000 by mkconf

```
ARRAY /dev/md/md2 metadata=1.2 name=md2 UUID=109fefd8:aa46fdd6:bddb613e:892bce00
ARRAY /dev/md/md3 metadata=1.2 name=md3 UUID=950bfa3c:f52d5cfd:9f9c1435:0d85a63f
ARRAY /dev/md/md0 metadata=1.2 name=ns3229089:md0 UUID=a38b6d22:2e7220cb:79f5ce7d:e0c3d63a
```

OS is fully updated. Tried:

1. Adding "resume=none" in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
2. Blacklisting btrfs in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`
3. Commented out "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset iommu=pt console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8" (not sure why this exists, it was added there by the default OVH installation)

No matter what I try, the OS always gets stuck on the same line.
I can enter recovery mode and play around with files, I just cannot boot the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.
The issue was with initramfs. Running the "sudo update-initramfs -u" command in recovery mode again seems to solve the issue.
Not entirely sure why this happens and needs more exploring. One assumption is that the mdadm.conf file has the initial OS installation RAID1 arrays written twice.
Anyway, I hope someone else finds this helpful.

Comment: Been using OVH servers for years. And been having this issue for years! keep in mind this is going to happen every single time there is a kernel update! I even gotten to a point where I no longer use their Raid but use the MDADM software to do it. 

You are also lucky you were able to boot in recovery because sometimes it even hangs there with no way to fix it other than re-installation. Only OVH seems to have this issue.

Comment: We slowly moving away from OVH because of this and similar issues. No point in having on-prem server that you cannot fully control.

Answer (score 0):

same problem and at the end it runs.
I had also at a moment a double declaration of the RAID ARRAYS in the madm.conf file, so i reduced to the more recent ones.
My server is a Debian 12, 2 SSD, 4 HD, fresh install.
In this action i don't mount the RAID 5 HD Array, only the RAID1 BOOT and RAID1 for /.
So in the recovery mode i've done this, as root user :

```
mount /dev/md126 /mnt
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc/
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys/
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev/
mount -t devpts devpts /mnt/dev/pts
mkdir -p /run/chroot/lock
mount -o bind /run/chroot /mnt/run
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
mount /dev/md127 /boot
source /etc/default/locale
update-initramfs -u -v
```

This mounts the root partition md126 and the boot partition md127. Switches with chroot, the root from the rescue to the root partition and create a new initramfs needed to boot with the needed scripts, binaries and kernel modules

Then exit, unmount cleanly and reboot.
thanks to all